# Using unique index for cross table constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm pretty new to Oracle and database design in general but I have a question. I have two basic tables called employee and department. The employee table holds a salary property. Now I need to implement a new business rule: The total of all employee salaries in one department (an employee is part of a department) may not exceed 200k. I know this can be done with a materialized view, but can it also be done with unique indexes? If so, how would one approach this particular situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use a unique index to enforce this sort of rule.

You could try to enforce this sort of rule via triggers but that tends to get rather difficult in a multiuser environment.  You'd need to do things like lock the `department` row to ensure that only one session can be modifying `employee` information for a particular `department` at a time which tends to introduce significant scalability issues.  It also tends to involve quite a bit of code to handle all the potential cases.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why it can't be done with indexes? I'm trying to avoid triggers for some reasons that regard the platform that I'm working on right now.

Comment: @TimKranen Indexes are for record location capabilities, not constraints. You're trying to create a constraint.

Comment: @TimKranen - I can't see how indexes would even be considered.  An index can only exist on a single table.  And an index stores row-level information not aggregated information.

Comment: Alright thanks! I'll research the triggers then. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with any indexes. But it is can be done using a trigger.

If you add a column `maxDeptSalary` to your `departments` table, then you can create a trigger on `Insert` and `Update` in which you

1. query your `maxDeptSalary` and get the value
2. run `Sum` on existing records in your employee table for that department
3. compare `sum + new.value <= maxDeptSalary`
4. Reject your record if criteria is not met

But the reality is, this is should be done on application level, not the database

Comment: You left out the step where you'd need to lock the row in the `department` table.  Otherwise, I can insert a row in one session and you can insert a row in another session, the tests can pass in both sessions, and then the rule is violated when we both commit.  Of course, that's one of the reasons that trigger-based solutions to this sort of problem are so hard to get right.

Comment: @JustinCave You're right. But I don't think such intricacies were in scope of this question.